# Django 1.7 python manage.py makemigrations polls SyntaxError

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am following the official Django documentation and trying to make the polls app.
But when I run the command python manage.py makemigrations polls I get the console error.

```
anupam@Anupam-HP:~/Python/django/mysite$ python manage.py makemigrations polls
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/django/                core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
django.setup()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/home/anupam/Python/django/mysite/polls/models.py", line 13



                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code I am using for the models is:

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
   question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
   choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   votes = models.IntegerField(default=
```

It would be great if you could point out the error.

Answer (score 2):

The error line is the last line of your `models.py`:

```
votes = models.IntegerField(default=
```

It should be:

```
votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```